# Canon wireless control with running intervalometer

Tags: canon, timelapse, wireless, intervalometer

Does anyone know if there is an iOS app (or mac os app) with what I can achieve the following:

1. Be able to wirelessly connect to my 77D camera (either wifi or bluetooth is fine)
2. Start the intervalometer (that step I can do on the camera manually)
3. Be able to wirelessly read the EV readings to asses my exposure
4. Be able to wirelessly (without interrupting the intervalometer) change ISO setting
5. Be able to wirelessly (without interrupting the intervalometer) change shutter speed.

That’s it. I don’t need live view, image previews, autofocusing etc.

What I want to do is to wirelessly adjust exposure when doing a twilight timelapse (a.k.a. Holy Grail timelapse) without standing out in the cold.

Also if there is another way to achieve my goal - please enlighten me

Comment: Related: [What is bulb ramping?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/19007)

Answer (score 1):

[qDslrDashboard](https://dslrdashboard.info/introduction/)'s "Auto Holy Grail" mode does [bulb ramping](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19007) from iOS over a wi-fi connection with your 77D. The iOS port of it is called ControlMyCamera and is a beta that requires [TestFlight](https://testflight.apple.com/join/6qhDHFFo) to install.

Bulb ramping is where the exposure settings are *automatically* adjusted between images in a timelapse sequence to maintain overall exposure in changing lighting conditions (e.g., sunset or sunrise).

The LrTimelapse guys have a youtube tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmVOHi4p1UA&t=4s

Unfortunately, [Magic Lantern](https://www.magiclantern.fm) does not yet have a build for the 77D, so you can't use its [intervalometer](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#intervalometer) with [auto ramping](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#bulb_focus_ramping) features.

Answer (score 0):

There are wired remotes (Neewer is one brand that comes to mind) that have an intervalometer built in.

Canon has their app to control the camera: https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/explore/solutions-services/mobile-apps/camera-connect

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for an iOS app for having intervallometer mode on my Canon M50, which cannot make long exposure timelapses. There is "Cascable" which cost $30 if you want to connect wirelessly on your DSLR, use the intervallometer mode and change the settings with your iPhone.

Comment: Welcome to Photo.Stackexchange. This is not an answer to the given question. If you have enough reputation you can make a comment but this is more like a new question so you should please ask it as a new one.

Comment: This almost answers the question. Can you verify if Cascable allows you to change the ISO or shutter speed setting of the camera _without interrupting an intervalometer sequence_?

Comment: @scottbb, it may not do that, but it looks like [it's scriptable](https://cascable.se/ios/recipes/) to some degree.

Comment: @inkista Wow, I think that app looks completely different than it did a couple years ago. I don't recognize it at all. Looks pretty impressive.